# Can't leave a comment on the Stack Exchange Gives Back blog post

Tags: support, blog

When trying to leave a comment in the [Stack Exchange Gives Back 2014](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-exchange-gives-back-2014/) blog post, I get error message:

> you must leave a valid email

I have tried with two emails, my usual one on SE and a gmail address, neither with any special characters.

Comment: You may to include how you can work from home and earn a living earning $$$$$$ just for sending out emails. Check out this link:

Comment: Erm.... Okay :-)

Comment: [status-wordpress-is-the-worst]

Comment: No repro for me with ordinary gmail address.